# center an image (in a div) for responsive design

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve the **image-popup-on-hover-over-text** similar to Wikipedia. The CSS is working fine **except when viewed on a mobile device**. Since the popup text can be on the far right or left (depending on the mobile device's screen width), the popup can **exceed the width of the screen** resulting in the size of the div exceeding the width of the rest of the page.

I've tried positioning the div using the commented out portions of the CSS. If the text is on the far right or left, it pushes the page wider.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.2; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    font-size: 1.0rem;
}
html { font-size: 90%; } 
body {
    background-color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {
    width: auto ;
    max-width: 100% ;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.top-page {
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
}
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    /*
    flex-flow: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    */
}
.popup_on_mouseover {/* - parent div - style for keyword */
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: thin dotted;
    background: #ffffb3;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.popup_on_mouseover:hover {
    text-decoration: none; 
    background: #ffff00;
    z-index: 66;
}
.popup_on_mouseover div {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-50%); 
    /*
    left: 50%;
    left: calc(50vw - 150px);
    transform: translateX(-50%); 
    transform: translateX(50%) translateX(-150px); /* nested */
    */
    
    top: 40px;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 280px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 5px 5px 5px;
    z-index:66;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 24px 30px -4px rgba(175,175,175,0.87); 
    box-shadow: 0px 24px 30px -4px rgba(175,175,175,0.87);
}

.popup_on_mouseover:hover div {
    visibility: visible;
} 
.hold-text {
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align:left;
}
img.resizeImg280x210 {
  display: block;
  width:280px;
  max-height:210px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.plainbrown12 {font-size: 1.2rem; color: #59493d }
.white12 {font-size: 1.2rem; color: #FFFFFF }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="top-page">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="hold-text plainbrown12">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                <div class="popup_on_mouseover">currency
                    <div>
                        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgV0R.png" class="resizeImg280x210">
                        <br>
                        <span class="white12">currency</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                , quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
                <div class="popup_on_mouseover">dude
                    <div>
                        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUW9T.jpg" width="280" height="210">
                        <br>
                        <span class="white12">dude</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                . Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
                <div class="popup_on_mouseover">dice
                    <div>
                        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOCT3.png" width="280" height="210">
                        <br>
                        <span class="white12">dice</span>
                    </div>
                </div>                
                non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Best case scenario would be to calculate the screen width and show the popup image just below the text, and for any screen width which puts the popup div off screen, move the div to it's on the left/right side of the parent div.

[popup text is in the center of the page, no issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT37d.png)

[popup text on left margin, image is off the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGHaj.png)

Comment: Can you possibly set the div to be as wide as the viewport with `max-width: 100vw;`?

Comment: Replacing **width: 300px;** with **max-width: 100vw;** results in the image being only about 20px wide...

Comment: width: 300px;
    max-width: 100vw;
Noticed that using both helps with the right margin, but for any highlighted text on the left margin, the popup image is off screen.

Comment: can use bootstrap with js?

Comment: Looking for a CSS solution

Comment: can try add the image as `background-image`?

Comment: The location on the page would still be the same whether the image was inside the div or as the background image of the div. Not sure how the browser window resizing would be effected, but don't see how that would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing, the text which triggers the pop-up can be basically anywhere on the line - at the beginning, middle or end. In this case, as the popup is position in relation to this, you cannot use CSS to adapt to that - you need JS.

Basically it would be along the lines of:
- mouseenter/mouseleave events to show/hide
- get the position of the 'hover' target
- check if it is near the side of the screen (half its size + the size of the pop-up itself)
- if it is too close, (and so it would not contain the whole image), make adjustments to it's position.

Comment: I was hoping to use **transform: translateX** in combination with **calc** (or something similar to that) to achieve the effect.